# Multiple transcripts encoding for one protein

Tags: proteins, transcription

Trying to get a better understanding of the process of DNA to proteins.

So when we have a gene, it is read from the 5' to 3' end, only translating the exons to mRNAs. A single gene can have multiple exons, and use alternative splicing to create different transcripts. A transcript may result in mRNA (not necessarily right? Also other kinds of RNA?) which is translated to amino acids. Finally folded to a functional protein.

My question here, are there different transcripts (say in different genes) that encode for the same protein?

Comment: Yes, they arise because of gene duplication but usually the protein is not exactly similar but quite similar. These genes are called paralogs.

Comment: yes, for example, if one gene came from you mother and another from your father, they might be different enough to cause disease (see sickle-cell anemia or cystic fibrosis).

Comment: As I understood it, a transcription is a combination of exons being used for, for instance, creation of proteins. I'm not referring to point mutations and such, because than another protein will be made by the transcript. Most probably not a protein which is created in another gene.

Comment: Gene duplication accounts for different the same proteins to be created in different parts of the chromosome, in an extreme case on a different chromosome. But in principle, the genes are the same, hence the transcript is the same. Are there, naturally (so we all have) different genes encoding for the same proteins

Comment: Any mutations in the 3' UTR of a transcript for a paralog would result in a different transcript which encodes for the same protein.

Comment: Just a point of clarification: you say "*it is read from the 5' to 3' end, only reading the exons*" but this is not the case. The cell's [transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_%28genetics%29) machinery reads the *entire* gene until it comes to a "stop" sequence. The resulting pre-mRNA is then [spliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_splicing) to produce the actual mRNA(s) that are translated into proteins. It is during this splicing that introns are cleaved out.

Comment: @MattDMo you're right. I skipped some steps...

Comment: @TomD interesting links! :-)